# --device-cgroup-rule in docker/podman doesn't work

Tags: docker, podman, cgroups

I tried to use in run command the option `--device-cgroup-rule` in docker/podman, without success.
The syntax is `-v /dev:/dev --device-cgroup-rule='c 189:* rmw'`, but all devices still available.
Thanks